# Programmatically installing & activating Wordpress plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible, somehow to programmatically install plugins? So I can send my client one file they unpack, go to some installplugins.php file and that installs + activates them? Only way I found for doing that is really rancid lowlevel; I'm hoping someone here knows better methods.

Comment: Have you read Wordpress code? It may be very helpful to check what Wordpress is doing, when you click "install" button.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Update

Today I use a shell loop with [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org) to install and [activate](http://wp-cli.org/commands/plugin/activate/) the plugins

## Original Answer

For activating, I use some variant of this. suppose I had three plugins i wanted to activate ("cforms",  "w3-total-cache",  "wordpress-seo").  The convention is that their directory and plugin .php file are the same name:

```
$wordpress_path = "/path/to/my/wordpress/install";    
require_once $wordpress_path . "/wp-load.php"; //not sure if this line is needed
//activate_plugin() is here:
require_once $wordpress_path . "/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php";
$plugins = array("cforms",  "w3-total-cache",  "wordpress-seo");
foreach ($plugins as $plugin){
$plugin_path = $wordpress_path."wp-content/plugins/{$plugin}.php";
  activate_plugin($plugin_path);
}
```

Comment: Some plugins use a different name for the primary PHP file from the plugin name. Does anybody know how to extract or detect the plugins primary PHP filename?

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy plugin to `/wp-content/plugins/` (root dir if the plugin is just one file, otherwise a subdir).
2. Call `activate_plugin('/full/path/to/your/plugin/php');`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete script; put in wp-admin, give it a .php suffix, and hit it via curl.

```
<?php

define('WP_ADMIN', TRUE);
define('WP_NETWORK_ADMIN', TRUE);
define('WP_USER_ADMIN', TRUE);

require_once('../wp-load.php');
require_once( '../wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
require_once( '../wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

activate_plugin("/full/path/to/my/plugin.php");
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you can toggle plugins in the database: table wp_options -> field option_name -> active_plugins.

Comment: Upvote gabrielk.  Not recommended; esp. if there's any magic in the activation hooks.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook

Comment: @BretWeinraub: My answer is over 4 years old, and the OP has accepted an answer.